# How to plot nested dictionary using matplotlib

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, matplotlib, nested

I have a nested dictionary like given below.

```
    {'a1-b1': {'label': 'ab1',
  'x_axis': array([ 1,  6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56, 61, 66, 71, 76, 81,
         86]),
  'y_axis_1': array([1.315, 1.29 , 1.29 , 1.295, 1.32 , 1.35 , 1.4  , 1.46 , 1.54 ,
         1.64 , 1.765, 1.93 , 2.135, 2.4  , 2.755, 3.24 , 3.955, 4.74 ]),
  'y_axis_2': array([0.18912254, 0.22628277, 0.25497109, 0.27911141, 0.30370315,
         0.32626577, 0.3506969 , 0.37465609, 0.40049521, 0.42780508,
         0.45713762, 0.49116357, 0.52798013, 0.56970844, 0.61884742,
         0.67655377, 0.74901601, 0.78038465])},  
 'a1-b2': {'label': 'ab2',
  'x_axis': array([ 1,  6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56, 61, 66, 71, 76, 81,
         86]),
  'y_axis_1': array([1.315, 1.29 , 1.29 , 1.295, 1.32 , 1.35 , 1.4  , 1.46 , 1.54 ,
         1.64 , 1.765, 1.93 , 2.135, 2.4  , 2.755, 3.24 , 3.95 , 4.455]),
  'y_axis_2': array([0.21220464, 0.25390022, 0.2860899 , 0.31317651, 0.34076963,
         0.36608599, 0.39349889, 0.42038227, 0.44937501, 0.480018  ,
         0.51293053, 0.55110929, 0.59241926, 0.63924044, 0.69437676,
         0.75912608, 0.83936971, 0.82298074])}}
```

I would like to use matplotlib to plot sub-plots using both sub-dictionaries. For `a1-b1` and `a1-b2` I like to plot `y_axis_1` against `x_axis_1` and would like to use corresponding labels using `label`. The titles of `x` and `y` axis should also be corresponding keys, i.e. `y_axis_1` and `x_axis_1`. Likewise, I would prefer to do a second plot which plots `y_axis_2` against `x_axis` with corresponding `label` and titles.
I am trying to access dictionary items using following, but I am stuck to proceed further. Thanks for your feedback in advance!

```
for i,outer_dict_key in enumerate(nested_dict):
    for key, value in nested_dict[outer_dict_key].items():
        keys = key
        values = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for j, outer_dict_key in enumerate(nested_dict):
        ax.plot(nested_dict[outer_dict_key]["x_axis"],
                nested_dict[outer_dict_key]["y_axis_"+str(i)],
                label=nested_dict[outer_dict_key]["label"])
    ax.legend(loc="upper left")
    ax.set_xlabel("x_axis")
    ax.set_ylabel("y_axis_"+str(i))
    plt.show()
```

The output is two plots (one for "y_axis_1" and the other for "y_axis_2"), with two lines in each ("ab1" and "ab2").

Answer (score 1):

If you call `nested_dict` your dictionary, you can do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for info in nested_dict.values():
    keys  = list(info.keys())
    vals  = list(info.values())
    plt.plot(vals[1], vals[2], label = keys[2])
    plt.plot(vals[1], vals[2], label = keys[3])
    plt.xlabel(keys[1])
    plt.title(vals[0])
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Should result: [image]